# QStandardItemModel: any efficient way to add a batch of items?

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel, qstandarditemmodel

Is there any efficient way to add a batch of `QStandardItem`s to a model? The model is being cleared and then I'm adding a lot of items. `QtreeWidget` has `addTopLevelItems ( const QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> & items )` for just this, how to optimize such addition with model / view architecture?

Comment: [`QStandardItemModel::appendColumn(const QList<QStandardItem *> & items)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qstandarditemmodel.html#appendColumn). Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @thuga: possibly, I'll give it a try. But what if I have many columns, too? Then it would still be inefficient.

Comment: Then use [`QStandardItemModel::appendRow(const QList<QStandardItem *> & items)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qstandarditemmodel.html#appendRow)?

Comment: @thuga: what if I have a large number of rows AND columns?

Comment: This depends a lot of your `QStandardItem`s. You can add rows/columns to them. Just like in `QTreeWidgetItem` you add columns to it, not to the `QTreeWidget` itself.

Comment: @thuga: that didn't occur to me, I should try it as well. Thanks!

Comment: If you care about efficiency, you'd better create your own model class.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: oh, I've tried to. Wasted a week trying to make it work.There's too many things about model / view system that I don't understand.